# How to access and modify the properties of an Object that is given as value for a Dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a `BaseItems` class that contains possible values of an item. New items can be declared as an Object of this class, and depending on the parameters they are of differing types (with constructor overloading). I use a `ItemsInitializers`class to initialize items. A Wallet item for example is declared below. I have a `player` object that has a `MyInventory` property, declared with the `MyInventory` class. To get into it basically, I have the following scenario:

```
player.MyInventory.AddItem("Wallet", ItemsInitializers.Wallet); ///"Wallet" is the key, the value is the Wallet object declared in ItemsInitializers.
```

and

```
Console.WriteLine(player.MyInventory.List["Wallet"]); ///outputs TextGame.Items.BaseItems
```

so I have no idea how to access the value property of the Wallet and how to even modify it. Should I give up on using a dictionary and just declare an object in the `Inventory` class that can make the access and modification of the desired property?

Thank you and I apologize for all the text, I don't know how to summarize it more. If possible, if there is anything I could've done better in the OOP logic I would also appreciate letting me know.

```
class BaseItems
    {
        public BaseItems(string Name, string Description, int Value) 
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Description = Description;
            this.Value = Value;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, string> Type { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        public float Amount { get; set; }
        public float Damage { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }


    }
```

```
    static class ItemsInitializers
    {
        public static BaseItems Wallet = new BaseItems("Wallet", "Money Storage", 20); /// first value is the name of the item, the second value is the description of the item, and the third value is the value of the item

    }
```

```
class Inventory
    {
        public Inventory()
        {

        }
        public string MyInventory { get; set; } = "My Inventory";
        public Dictionary<string, BaseItems> List { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, BaseItems>();

        public void AddItem(string ItemName, BaseItems item)
        {
            List.Add(ItemName, item);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Feels like you're 9/10th of the way there? `player.MyInventory.List["Wallet"]` gives you the `BaseItem` object, so you can do `player.MyInventory.List["Wallet"].Value` for example. What are you trying to modify?

Comment: @Matt ah wow, did not know I can access the properties of a dictionary value that way. I will try to add a method in the BaseItems that can deduct/add to the value. If it works, thank you.

Comment: you had done the hard bit :). Now you can make it more robust. You probably will want to access the values of dictionaries using `List.TryGetValue` as if `"Wallet"` did not exist, you'll get a Null Reference Exception with the `player.MyInventory.List["Wallet"].Value` code

Comment: You'll probably want to encapsulate some variables and access them with getters and setters too to make it more robust.

Comment: @Matt ok it works with a method to deduct the value, I was outputting it like this ```Console.WriteLine(player.MyInventory.List["Wallet"].Value);```. If I understand right, I should add a method to the ```Inventory``` class that contains a loop that goes through ```List``` and looks for the key, then returns the value (or the value of the property of the value :D) of that key?

Comment: @Badda great suggestion, I will make the variables private and make them accessible and settable only with get and set methods. Thanks :).

Comment: @Matt I understood now, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8. Thanks for the suggestion :).